# Update current user data (FastAPI + MongoDB)

Tags: python, mongodb, crud, fastapi

I'm trying to figure out how to update data for a logged in user in FastAPI.

I've got a CRUD of users where an admin can perform operations. On the other hand, I've got two methods related to a normal user, a get for his data:

```
  @router.get("/me")
  async def get_current_user(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_verified_user)):
  user = UserOut(
    first_name=current_user.first_name,
    last_name=current_user.last_name,
    email=current_user.email
  )
  return user
```

and a put in case they want to update their data. This one is the method where I'm struggling:

```
@router.put("/current", response_model=User)
async def update_user(user_update: UserUpdateCurrent = Body(...), current_user: User = Depends(get_current_verified_user)):
user = await User.find_one(User.id == current_user.id)
if user_update.password:
    user.hashed_password = get_password_hash(user_update.password)
    await user.save()
user_update = {k: v for k, v in user_update.dict().items() if v is not None}
update_query = {"$set": {
    field: value for field, value in user_update.items()
}}
user.updated = datetime.utcnow()
await user.update(update_query)
return user
```

Okay this works, but I feel it's not efficient and maybe insecure. Also, this line:

```
user.updated = datetime.utcnow()
```

always gets triggered, no matter if there are changes introduced or not. How could I update the date only when a new value is entered with the UserUpdateCurrent object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Compare the current values to the submitted values to decide whether a change has occured; exactly how you do that will depend on which fields you want to consider and what the difference between your user submission data and the data stored in your db is. You can also replace your `get` controller with `response_model=UserOut` and just `return current_user` (you might need to have `orm_mode = True` configured for your response model, if you don't already have that)

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Mongo, and I am assuming you use PyMongo or Motor, the update API gives you the number of documents updated by your query. You can use that information to know if you have performed a valid update or not.

Also to be safe in a scaled deployment, its better to not `find` and then update, rather perform an `update` directly.